# Spring MVC @RequestMapping change character of url in redirect

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have spring-mvc method that request mapping is like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/person/{personId}/**")
```

in jsp i set url like :

```
/person/2/اکبر اکبری
```

and it is no problem.

when in other method of controller , i am redirecting to this url the address bar of browser shows this:

```
/person/2/??? ???
```

What is wrong?what do i do?

Comment: make sure to use UTF-8 *everywhere*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the special Arabic characters when sending a URL to the browser, as only ASCII characters can be used:

```
String url = "/person/2/" + URLEncoder.encode("اکبر اکبری", "UTF-8");
```